# How can you do a conditional where clause using Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can you do a conditional where clause?  I have a rake task that runs a query.  Say I am building a query like so:

```
residentials = Residential.where(:is_active => true)
```

Now if I pass a certain parameter to the rake task, I want to add to the where clause.  I was thinking something like this:

```
residentials.where(:something_else => true) if param_was_passed
```

But that just replaces the existing where clause.  How can I add it to the existing where clauses?

Comment: Is this parameter for a specific field in your `Residential` model?

Comment: in fact you are not using arel here.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It is possible to chain where statements

```
residentials = Residential.where(:is_active => true)
residentials = residentials.where(:other_thing => true) if param_was_passed
```

This should work.

Make sure this is not the last line in a function call; repeat the `residentials` variable as the last line in that case. (As per @digger69 comment)

Comment: That's what I tried but it didn't work.  I'll check it again and add output here

Comment: This should work, but be careful if you're relying on this being returned from a function since the function returns the value of the last statement which will be nil if !param_was_passed

Answer (score 25):

You could build up the hash and then provide it to the `.where` method. Something like:

```
h = { }
h[:is_active] = true
h[:field_x] = true if param_was_passed

residentials = Residential.where(h)
```

Comment: How to do `where('created_at > ?', 10.days.ago)` in this case?